# Strange LiveData behaviour?

Tags: java, android, mvvm, viewmodel, android-livedata

Im trying to implement MVVM architecture using ViewModel and LiveData. These two methods are inside a Activity:

```
 private void handleResult(BoardViewModel vm) {
        vm.getLiveDataSingleObj("Result").observe(this, new Observer<Object>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable Object resultObj) {
                Result result = (Result) resultObj;
                if (!result.isCompleted()) return;
                gotoResult();
            }
        });
    }
```

And

```
private void gotoResult() {
        Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Result: Moving to next activity");
        Intent intent = new Intent(boardActivity, ResultActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("LEVEL", levelIndex);
        intent.putExtra("MAP", mapIndex);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

The handleResult method is setup to listen for result objects that indicate that the game has ended and it is time to move on to the next activity ("gotoResult"). However, this completely breaks the navigation of the app, when i go back and then say attempt to start a new game session i instead instantly go to the next activity telling me I've already won.

Any ideas as to why it fires multiple times and eventually stops, letting me start a new session. To clarify, if I remove the gotoResult the logic works every single time no errors with indexes out of bounds or what have you, it's only when I add the goto that everything breaks.

ViewModel:

```
private void setupHashTypes() {
        hashLiveData.put(KEY_BOARD, liveDataBoardQuery);
        hashLiveData.put(KEY_STEPS_COUNTER, game.getStepsTakenLiveData());
        hashLiveData.put(KEY_PATH_CHANGE, game.getPathChangedLiveData());
        hashLiveData.put(KEY_VALUE_CHANGE, game.getValueChangeLiveData());
        hashLiveData.put(KEY_TIMER, game.getTimerLiveData());
        hashLiveData.put(KEY_SELECTED, game.getSelectedLiveData());
        hashLiveData.put(KEY_DESELECTED, game.getDeselectedLiveData());
        hashLiveData.put(KEY_HOLD, game.getHoldLiveData());
        hashLiveData.put(KEY_UNHOLD, game.getUnholdLiveData());
        hashLiveData.put(KEY_RESULT, game.getResultLiveData());
    }

    public LiveData<Object> getLiveDataSingleObj(String type) {
        if (hashLiveData.containsKey(type)) {
            return (LiveData<Object>) hashLiveData.get(type);
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid: key was not found: " + type);
    }
```

And the Model has getters, example:

```
  private final SingleLiveEvent<Result> resultLiveData = new SingleLiveEvent<>();
    public LiveData<Result> getResultLiveData() {
        return resultLiveData;
    }
```

Comment: please show the viewModel code that emit the completed state of your object

Comment: I added some parts of the ViewModel and Model, though the issue has been solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing from MutableLiveData which always resends the previous set values to new subscribers, to SingleLiveEvent which doesn't have this behaviour, solved the problem.

The class can be found here: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/dev-todo-mvvm-live/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp

Answer (score 1):

you should remove the observer in `onDestroy()` method

Comment: Your solution might work. The problem I've come to understand is because a behaviour of LiveData is that it sends the latest value to each new observer. So when i start the second game session, it recieves the latest result transmitted, instantly ending the game session. 

Another solution is to use something called SingleLiveEvent, which I've yet figured out how to do, but does only pass new data to the observers and not the latest pushed data.

Comment: If the state of livedata is not resetted, in onStart method the latest value will be redelivered.